# Ng test no funciona

Tags: nodejs, angular, pruebas-unitarias, karma-jasmine, jasmine

estoy nuevo en el tema de unit testing de angular, estoy tratando de inicializar los test con el comando ng test pero no funciona me sale el siguiente error

**An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\xxxxx\administration-web\node_modules@angular\material'
See "C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fLsIqJ\angular-errors.log" for further details.**

Por lo que veo es que falta el modulo de material de angular (no lo estoy usando porque estoy actualmente con primeng) entonces trato de realizar la instalación de angular material pero tambien me da error.

No se si es un problema de compatibilidad del paquete de material y de angular core, agradezco mucho si me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema, dejo el package.json

```html
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: administration-web@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@13.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"13.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"13.2.2" from @angular/animations@13.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^13.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"13.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

```html
{
  "name": "administration-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration prod",
    "build-qa": "ng build --configuration qa",
    "build-dev": "ng build --configuration dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration dev",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.5",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.19.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
    "angular-datatables": "^13.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.11.3",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.11.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.1.0",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^13.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Eso pasa cuando hay dependencias y tu tienes instalada otra version, ejemplo tienes anguar 14 y el package que quieres instalar usa angular 13, lo que puedes hacer es agregar force o legacy-peer-deps: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: Checa esto para mas info al respecto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps